# mongoose remove does not remove all documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections (User and Offer) and I use async to do a series of operations, but the last document is not removed.

```
async.series([
  function (callback) {
    User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
        user = result;
        callback();
      });
    },
    function (callback) {
      Offer.find({_owner: user._id}, function (err, offers) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        var i = offers.length;
        while (i--) {
          var offer = offers[i];
          Offer.remove(offer, function (err) {
            return callback(err);
          });
        }
        callback();
      });
    },
    function (callback) {
      User.remove(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
      });
      callback();
    }
    ], function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(503).json({message: err});
      }
      res.status(200).json({message: 'User and offers successfully deleted'});
    });
```

I turned mongoose debugging on and I see that 8 documents for this user are removed (as expected). Example message:

```
Mongoose: users.remove({ active: true, role: 'user', favoredOffers: [], 
salt: 'qIADYcMS3SiAuF3M007E9g==', hashedPassword: '**', emailVerified: true, 
name: 'Test', email: 'test1@test.com', emailVerificationToken: '***', 
updatedAt: new Date("Mon, 21 Sep 2015 00:52:58 GMT"), 
createdAt: new Date("Mon, 21 Sep 2015 00:52:58 GMT"), 
_id: ObjectId("55ff54ea1d6201ff42ea0045") }) { 
safe: { w: 'majority', wtimeout: 10000 } }
```

When I run a test the result is, that this one document remains. At first I thought my test runs too fast (async.waterfall) but then I switched to async.series and the behaviour remains and when I look into the test-db the document is still there.

Test code:

```
it.only('should allow deleting my account and all my offers if my password was right', function (done) {
    async.series([function (callback) {
        login(server, server.delete('*url*'), 'test@test.com', 'testpwd1', function (server) {
            server
                .send({password: 'testpwd1'})
                .expect(200)
                .end(callback);
        });
    }, function (callback) {
        User.findOne({email: 'test1@test.com'}, function (err, user) {
            callback(user ? new Error('user was still found in mongo') : null); //misuse not found user as 'error'-object
        });
    }, function (callback) {
        Offer.find({_owner: user1._id}, function (err, offers) {
            expect(offers).to.have.length(0);
            callback();
        });
    }], done);
});
```

Result: Uncaught AssertionError: expected [ Array(1) ] to have a length of 0 but got 1

Wether I am missing something or I don't understand the behaviour of the mongdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst the operations are being called in series per those that are split in the `async.series` the problem here is the `while` loops are not asynchronously controlled, and therefore the callbacks to move to the next stage are being called before all removal is complete.

You could use [`async.whilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) to control the callbacks from the [`.remove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) operations, but that would be overkill since you really should just be issuing ther "query" directly to `.remove()` rather than trying to work with a list returned by `.find()`:

```
async.series(
    [
        function (callback) {
          Offer.remove({ "_owner": req.user._id}, callback);
        },
        function (callback) {
          User.remove({ "_id": req.user._id },callback);
        }
    ],
    function (err,results) {
      if (err) {
          res.status(503).json({message: err});
      } else {
          if ( Array.sum(results) == 0 ) {
              res.status(404).json({message: 'User not found'});
          } else {
              res.status(200).json({message: 'User and offers successfully deleted'});
          }
      }
    }
);
```

Of course if the result of the remove operations did not remove anything, then you know the input did not match the user.

The async library allows callback passing so you don't need to control each stage. Any errors immediately go to the end block, along with the results of each stage. Also look at [`parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) instead for this case as one stage is not dependent on the other to complete first.

Comment: One thing I missed was, that I need a pre 'remove' hook to be triggered for each removed document and the Model.remove() does not trigger those.

Comment: @Iralution I'm really only showing you a way to check for the other condition that you missed which is "not found" which would occur when both modified counts ( returned by callback ) are 0. I do tend to patch that function in, but the full definition is an `Array.prototyp.reduce` i.e `results.reduce(function(p,n) { return p+n })`

Comment: @Iralution If it's not in your question then you don't get an answer that says that. People can only answer the questions you ask. If you have another question then post [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)